# Set identity Seed to a dynamic value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

We wanted to set the identity seed using

DBCC CHECKIDENT('myTable', RESEED, 0)

but we are udner the impression that the service account which runs that code must be assigned to the db_ddladmin role to be able to do this. Is this true? If so, this is a no-go for us because of policy.

If so, this is an alternative that i was considering:

```
--Create a test table


/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[People2]    Script Date: 03/22/2012 19:07:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People2](
    [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_People2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


---Proof of concept

declare @seed int = 1000 --Set the seed

SET IDENTITY_INSERT People2 ON

--Insert a dummy record to increment the identity counter to 1 less than the value that we really want
Insert into people2
(PersonId, LastName,FirstName)
values
(@seed-1, 'temp','dummy')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT People2 OFF

--Delete the record that we just inserted (for no otehr purpose than setting the seed)
delete from People2 where personid = @seed-1  

--Do your normal code to populate the People2 dest table
Insert into people2
(LastName,FirstName)
values
('Jones','John')

--Verify that the seed was set to the value we wanted

select * from People2
```

Other considerations are inserting into a temp table that we create using dynamic SQL that contains the identity seed value taken from a variable.

Less attractive approaches would be to cursor through the records and increment ID manually instead of it being an automatically column.

Tally tables are a possibility but are confusing to me.

Suggestions?

Comment: First, if you are unsure about the permissions, just check the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx Second, it would help if you could explain why you need to do this, because it's not obvious why you care what the current identity value is. Identity values are intended to be used for artificial keys, where the actual value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to have `ALTER` permissions on the table, you could use [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) for your first value.  This would update the seed for you.

From the link above regarding use of SET IDENTITY_INSERT:

```
If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for the table,
SQLServer automatically uses the new inserted value as the current identity value
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People2](
[PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,   ...
```

Comment: Let's say that  "check number" is  the identity column of the table and I know that I have 1 million checks to write and I don't know what the starting # will be until I run the process.

Comment: If you are passing a variable then what is stopping you from using that variable in the create statement.   If this is input data then why IDENTITY?